# How to populate Spinner from Database Android?

Tags: android, database, spinner, populate

I want to populate a spinner dropdown to show list from calling a background thread. My code is not working.

```
ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.add(nameOfMethod(), items);
    itemspin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.itemSpin);
    itemspin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Define not working.  What is it doing and what did you expect?

Comment: It shows error on this part adapter.add(nameOfMethod(), items);

Comment: I'm not sure if I should use adapter.add

Answer (score 0):

```
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

// database handler
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

            // Spinner Drop down elements
            List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

            // Creating adapter for spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
itemspin.setAdapter(adapter);
```